# How to check if input string is valid active directory userPrincipalName?

Tags: c#, active-directory

User will input his wanted login name and I need to create active directory user by given name. So I need to validate it for AD userPrincipalName rules. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I have searched for answer on internet but I haven't found anything that could do it (a bit strange :D) I just know that there is such command StringHelper.RemoveDiacritics but is it enough and correct to use in this case?

Comment: Well, the real way to validate it is to simply try and create the AD user account with that name and see if it fails or succeeds.

Comment: @ Chris:  I don't agree completely.  If we have a chance to check before hand, we can prevent some major headaches.  It is possible that no GC is available, and though the UPN is taken in another domain, it could be reassigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only query the UPN (Forest wide so do a globalcatalog search).  If the DirectorySearcher returns an object, the UPN is in use.

You would also need to check that the planed samAccountName is not in use in the target domain, and that the planed user **Name** is not in the destination OU or Container.  In both searches, as above, if the DirectorySearcher returns results, you must not continue, but chose alternatives.

Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/10/understanding-unique-attributes-in-active-directory.aspx) to find which attributes must be unique, but bear in mind, although the user's **Name** attribute is not mentioned in the table, it is being refered to in example 1.